# Good example of how to document graph structure made in Neo4j or OrientDB

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory, orientdb

Is there any best practise or good example which shows how to document graph ontologies.

Comment: You want an example of documentation for a graph DB?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to document your graph database structure.

I like the idea of [neo4j graph gists](https://neo4j.com/graphgists/). It is possible to generate such interactive graph gist using a regular github asciidoc gist which contains cypher code to describe your graph.

[Example Neo4j Graph Gist](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/34b3cf4c-da1e-4650-81e4-3a7107336ac9)

[Github Gist Source](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/blob/3.0/cypher/cypher-query-language/example/first-steps-cypher.adoc)

At some point it was also possible to host your own neo4j graph gist portal but I'm not sure whether this is still possible.